# Use ASP.Net MVC only for mobile clients

Tags: c#, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

We currently have a large ASP.Net webforms website , and we just started converting some parts of it to asp.net MVc

We want to create a version of the site specifically for mobile clients, and we would like to start off using MVC for that.

I know that MVC supports by convention that views files ending in .mobile are served for mobile clients. But my question is - how would i set things up in general that desktop clients still use default.aspx but that mobile clients get redirected to /home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for browser detection should be put in a base class that all your pages will derive from. Try below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsMobileBrowser())
    {
         Response.Redirect("/home");    
         return;      
    }

    // your other code
} 

public static bool IsMobileBrowser()
{
    //GETS THE CURRENT USER CONTEXT
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    //FIRST TRY BUILT IN ASP.NT CHECK
    if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        return true;
    }
    //THEN TRY CHECKING FOR THE HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE HEADER
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"] != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    //THEN TRY CHECKING THAT HTTP_ACCEPT EXISTS AND CONTAINS WAP
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null && 
        context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wap"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    //AND FINALLY CHECK THE HTTP_USER_AGENT 
    //HEADER VARIABLE FOR ANY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
    {
        //Create a list of all mobile types
        string[] mobiles =new[]
        {
              "midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo", 
              "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", 
              "240x320", "opwv", "chtml",
              "pda", "windows ce", "mmp/", 
              "blackberry", "mib/", "symbian", 
              "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi",
              "phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", 
              "SIE-", "SEC-", "samsung", "HTC", 
              "mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony"
              , "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx", 
             "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", 
             "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch",
             "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", 
             "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", 
             "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",
             "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", 
             "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "dddi", 
             "moto", "iphone"
        };

        //Loop through each item in the list created above 
        //and check if the header contains that text
        foreach (string s in mobiles)
        {
            if(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

See more at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213825/ASP-net-Mobile-device-detection

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I'm gonna use this approach but I'll use the 51Degrees mobile device database

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if (request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
{
 //rediret the user to mobile views
}
```

make sure you remove webform View Engine. like this. [MobileCompatibleViewEngine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx)

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<WebFormViewEngine>().First());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine()); // this will come from Nuget Package.
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in to Global.asax.

If user will access the website through Desktop it will automatically redirect to Desktop website weather user access through Android phone it will 
automatically redirect to mobile website

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DisplayModes.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Android")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
                ("Android", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });

        DisplayModes.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("WindowsPhone")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
                ("Windows Phone OS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });
    }
```

Comment: This would only work if the startup page is the home controler - not a aspx page